# RayCastHit in unity ignores objects and goes to point zero

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a bot for a tank game and right now I am trying to make him evade Obstacles. For that I am using RayCastHit, the problem is that my RayCastHit seams to ignore obstacles. So far I have

```
public float sensor_length = 10f;
```

shows how long the sensor is allowed to be

```
 public float car_length = -5f;
```

the tank is spun with 180 degrees, and this causes the sensor to come from front.
In a Method I have:

```
    RaycastHit hit;
    Vector3 sensorStartpos = transform.position;
    sensorStartpos.z += car_length;
    if(Physics.Raycast(sensorStartpos,transform.forward,out hit,sensor_length))
    { }
    Debug.DrawLine(sensorStartpos, hit.transform.position);
```

So I am getting my object transform point, then locate the front of it and it should fire a RayCast. Here comes the problem, as shown I didnt identify `hit` so its value is `null` and in the `if` statement I should fire one check to the next obstacle, but instead it fires one to point (0,0,0) (I am guessing because `hit = null`
How do I cause it to hit an obstacle instead?
(The debug line on the bottom causes the Ray Cast to be visualized)

Comment: What does 'Debug.DrawLine(sensorStartpos, sensorStartpos + sensor_length * transform.forward)' look like?

Comment: the problem was transform.forward it needed to be transform.point. Thanks anyhow

Comment: @Hendrik Feel free to write up your own answer to accept.